# Access dynamic amount of SQL Views

Tags: c#, sql, view

I believe this is a toughie!

I have 2 databases. `Destiny` and `Source`

In `Destiny` I have a table, which contains a list of names of views.

Such as:

```
GasPriceSourceID    Name
1   ICIS Heren TTF Bid
2   ICIS Heren TTF Offer
3   ICIS Heren TTF Midspread
4   NPG Spot
8   AEQ SYS Sell
9   AEQ SYS Buy
10  ICIS Heren Gaspool Midspread
```

So first I will call the View: `ICIS Heren TTF Bid` on the database: `Source`
Then `ICIS Heren TTF Offer` and so on.

This will be done in a C# console application.

Normally I would use a ADO.NET Entitiy Data Model. But this creates a static model of the database - but views will be added and removed daily.

All the views return 3 things: `ID`, `Date`, and `Value`.

I need to move these prices to a table in the database: `Destiny`

So in short. Destiny has a list of price sources. Each source has a lot of prices, which will be put into a table on Destiny.

Comment: dynamic sql.  be careful of injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide enough details just some general pointers:

- Build the SQL strings "manually" in the app
  NOT recommended and prone to problems (Security, Performance...)
- Build a stored procedure which in turn builds and execute the SQL SELECT and returns a CURSOR
  Can be a bit more secure (esp. can avoid SQL injection) since the Stored Procedure would check for the existence of the View first...

BTW: what exactly are you doing when you access those Views ?

**EDIT - after more information from OP:**

I suspect your model is a bit off... what you describe would VERY EASILY be solved by having EXCATLY ONE View with the columns `Source`, `ID`, `Date`, and `Value`.

This would make all the dynamic SQL and the resulting problems just go puff... because then you could just use "normal queries" with a `WHERE Source = 'ICIS Heren TTF Bid'` for example... any other technology like EF and/or LINQ etc. would be available and working "out of the box"...

Comment: Added a little more info. Feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Ah, but I do not control the views at the Source DB. I only control Destiny. Also, in the future, the prices might go to different tables on destiny. So view x,y,z go into table a on Destiny. x,z,g goes to table b on destiny etc.

Comment: the second part about `Desitny` is no problem... the first part is... so you are stuck with one of the options I named first in my answer (before the EDIT)...